# Simplified way to add up integer values from a JSON

Tags: node.js, json, addition

I have the following data structure

```
{
  metadata: {
    a: 0,
    b: 4,
    c: 1,
    d: 6
  }
}
```

I want to find a simple way to add all the variables in the metadata together without having to do them one at a time.. like metadata.a + metadata.b + metadata.c + metadata.d

I am hoping for a way to just add whatever variable exists in that

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simplified using ES6**

```js
const data = {
  metadata: {
    a: 0,
    b: 4,
    c: 1,
    d: 6
  }
}
const sum = Object.entries(data.metadata).reduce((sum, x) => sum+ x[1], 0)
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: this is exactly what im looking for.. perfect!!

Comment: thanks!! Hope! it helped u

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop for that

```js
const metadata = {
  a: 0,
  b: 4,
  c: 1,
  d: 6
}

let sum = 0

for (let key in metadata) {
  sum += metadata[key]
}
console.log(sum)
```